# Simple number theory proof confirmation

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Bear with me as I have never studied number theory and so my "proof" may not necessarily be of the same style that number theory might usually use.

I was attempting to prove legendre's conjecture (mostly to play around with the numbers and kill time), which if you are not familiar with asserts the following:

> For all integers n, there exists a prime number p such that $n^2 < p < (n+1)^2$

My proof is as follows:

$$x^2 < p < x^2 + 2x + 1$$

$\implies$ subtract $1$ from both sides

$$x^2 - 1 < p-1 < x^2 + 2x$$

$\implies$ by the fact that these are integral valued

$$x^2 < p \leq x^2 + 2x$$

$\implies x^2 + 2x$ is never prime

$$x^2 < p < x^2 + 2x$$

$\implies$ subtract $x^2$

$$0 < p - x^2 < 2x$$

$\implies$ divide by $x$

$$0 < p/x - x < 2$$

$\implies$ floor both sides

$$0 < \lfloor p/x \rfloor - x < 2$$

$\implies$ add $x$ to both sides

$$x \leq \lfloor p/x \rfloor < 2+x$$

$\implies$ multiply by $-x$

$$-x^2 \geq -x \lfloor p/x \rfloor > -x^2-2x$$

$\implies$ add $p$ to both sides

$$p - x^2 \geq p - x \lfloor p/x \rfloor > p - x^2 - 2x$$

$\implies$ reduce (modulo is always greater than $0$)

$$p - x^2 \geq p \mod x > 0 > p - x^2 - 2x$$

$\implies$ let $x$ be an even number $2n$

$$p - 4n^2 \geq p \mod 2n > 0$$

$\implies$ take modulo of $2$

$$(p - 4n^2) \mod 2 \geq (p \mod 2n) \mod 2 > 0$$

$\implies$ reduce: we assume it is proven that $(a \mod bc) \mod b = a \mod b$ due to periodicity

$$p \mod 2 \geq p \mod 2 > 0$$

It would appear that I proved the conjecture for even integral values, which I believe was stated to have been proved in the page I read about the conjecture. Is this proof valid or did my last steps just mess up the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remarks:

- The statement of Legendre's conjecture that you stated is not right. It is meant for $n$ being a positive integer.
- We are trying to write a proof about the existence of $p$, we can't start with the assumption that it exists.
- I can't comprehend the argument about taking modulo.

Comment: Can you show us how to write it from bottom up then? Note that $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$ are different. That is not everything can be written from bottom up.

Comment: Your main flaw: proving something is consistent doesn't tell us anything about the original stuff that you are trying to prove. Consider the statement "If today is a Monday, Dilbert has to work" I have checked that "Dilbert is working"(consistency) but I cannot conclude that it's a "Monday", it could be a "Friday". the statement "Today is a monday" has not been proven. In your case "Today is a Monday" is legendre conjecture for even number. and your verification that something is consistent can't be used to conclude that the legendre conjecture is true for even number.

Comment: Yes, to prove a statement is true, you just have to prove another statement that is equivalent. (you should be able to move forward and backward between these two statements).
Agree with your new Dilbert example.
Also, another example. Is "$1=3$ " a true statement? if I take modulo $2$, I get "$1=1$".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46822/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-thegreatduck).